# Laravel seeding

Tags: laravel, php

```
db:seed [--class[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force]
Class PostsSeeder does not exist
```

при

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Помогите, не получается сидить﻿.

Comment: Перепроверьте:
1. название файла
2. название класса
3. права доступа к файлу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл `PostsSeeder.php` действительно лежит в папке, которая подхватывается автолодером (см. секцию autoload файла `composer.json`), возможно стоит перегенерить classmap:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Если у вас Laravel 4, то есть еще:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```